# Что есть недопустимый сексуальный контент в google play?

Tags: android, google-play-console, playmarket

я сделал приложение, похожее на приложение для знакомств.
Дело в том - там много фотографий женщин, и я уже получил один suspended за Sexual Policy Violation...
я хочу это исправить, но я вообще то непонимаю что есть именно "Explisit Sexual Content", за что я могу быть забанен снова...
девушка в бикини на пляже или в бассейне-это нарушение?
женщина в короткой юбке -нарушение?
и т.д...

Answer (score 1):

Вообще можно зайти в [документацию Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9878810?hl=en#zippy=%2Cexamples-of-common-violations) ([или сюда](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10477564?hl=en)):

> - Depictions of sexual nudity, or sexually suggestive poses in which the subject is nude, blurred or minimally clothed, and/or where the
>   clothing would not be acceptable in an appropriate public context.
> - Depictions, animations or illustrations of sex acts, or sexually suggestive poses or the sexual depiction of body parts.
> - Content that depicts or are functionally sexual aids, sex guides, illegal sexual themes and fetishes.
> - Content that is lewd or profane - including but not limited to content which may contain profanity, slurs, explicit text,
>   adult/sexual keywords in the store listing or in-app.
> - Content that depicts, describes, or encourages bestiality.
> - Apps that promote sex-related entertainment, escort services, or other services that may be interpreted as providing sexual acts in
>   exchange for compensation.
> - Apps that degrade or objectify people, such as apps that claim to undress people or see through clothing, even if labelled as prank or
>   entertainment apps.

в вашем случае:

> - Изображения сексуальной наготы или позы с сексуальным подтекстом, в которых объект обнажен, размыт или минимально одет, и / или одежда
>   неприемлема в соответствующем общественном контексте.
> - Изображения, анимация или иллюстрации половых актов, поз сексуального характера или сексуальных изображений частей тела.
> - Контент, изображающий или являющийся функционально сексуальными помощниками, секс-руководствами, незаконными сексуальными темами и
>   фетишами.
> - Непристойный или непристойный контент, включая, помимо прочего, контент, который может содержать ненормативную лексику, оскорбления,
>   явный текст, ключевые слова для взрослых / сексуального характера в
>   описании магазина или в приложении
> - Приложения, рекламирующие секс-развлечения, эскорт-услуги или другие услуги, которые могут быть истолкованы как предоставление
>   сексуальных услуг в обмен на компенсацию.
> - Приложения, которые унижают достоинство или объективизируют людей, например приложения, которые утверждают, что раздевают людей или видят
>   сквозь одежду, даже если они помечены как приложения для шуток или
>   развлечений.

Если у вас есть картинки с животными:

> - Контент, изображающий, описывающий или поощряющий зоофилию

Я бы вам посоветовал обратиться в [Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10357403?hl=en&ref_topic=9877065) если вы не согласны с данным решением. Я думаю вам расскажут как правильнее поступить в этой ситуации.

Comment: Эти правила я видел, но согласитесь - они немного размыты...а так как проверку осуществляет бот, и нихто не церемониться - сразу банят, хотел бы знать чётко что можна а что нельзя...

Comment: тогда только в поддержку, эти доки будут в разных интерпретациях по сети вероятнее всего, где каждый будет писать то как он  это понимает. Я бы советовал обратиться в поддержку с таким вопросом, они посмотрят отчёт бота и смогут что-то удобоваримое сказать

Comment: Частые обращения в тех.поддержку - повод для бана акка. Единственное что можно сделать чтобы снизить вероятность бана (убрать совсем не получится - бот тупой, а тех.поддержка - ужасна) - вручную модерировать все фото, убирая то, что вам лично кажется плохим для бота гугла.

Comment: согласен что может  быть бан, но мне кажется что если вы ни разу не обращались то за один раз вам точно не прилетит)

Comment: Что то не радужно от таких ответов...)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.